# Does Distinct() After sorted() gives different result rather use independent stream?

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream, distinct

I have used distenict() after sorted() and same on list stream both gives diff result

```
    List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("aaaaa", "b", "lll", "kkk", "kkk");
    List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("h", "kkk", "mmmm");

    List<String> list3 = Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println("=======================================");
    list3.stream().distinct().sorted(Comparator.comparing(String::length)).forEach(System.out::println);
    ; // System.out.println(g);
    System.out.println("=======================================");
    list3.stream().distinct().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.
Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have.

Comment: The first stream pipeline prints the distinct elements sorted by increasing string length, the second stream pipeline prints the distinct elements in encounter order. What else did you expect?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are asking why your second call of `distinct()` in line

```
list3.stream().distinct().forEach(System.out::println);
```

does not print out the same result as the first time for the line

```
list3.stream().distinct().sorted(Comparator.comparing(String::length)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

This is because you are working on a stream of the elements from the list. First you take only distinct results from this stream and then you are sorting this stream before you are printing it.

All these operations happen only on the **stream**. They do not modify the backing list of the stream. So the order and content of the elements in the List stay the same.

So your second distinct stream happens on the same original not sorted list.